# highstock 1.3 / highcharts 3.0 beta navigator lagging

Tags: performance, highcharts, navigator

I currently have three separate y axis displayed offset below each other with about 4 series (3 line, 1 arearange) per axis with up to 26,000 points per series. 
 I have been using highstock 1.2.5 and the performance has been very responsive. I tried updating to highstock 1.3 and the chart rendered just fine but when I try to interact with the chart using the navigator it seems very laggy and unresponsive. Moving the extremes of the navigator is not smooth, when in the previous version it was very smooth. 

Is there anything that may have changed in the latest version that could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Could you create example with that poor performance? jsFiddle would be nice.

Comment: Her is a quick test I just tried:

I took an example of one of the highstock jsfiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

and then changed the version of the code to the latest beta:
http://jsfiddle.net/etre0/fTwLr/

Using the latest code moving the extremes of the navigator seems to perform slower. But it also looks like the chart is being re-rendered as the navigator is being dragged (something that does not seem to happen in the old code). Is this the intended behavior? Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: I have tested it in both Chrome and Firefox with the same results

Comment: I have added a console log to print on redraw events. In the new version moving the navigator extremes fires multiple render events, while the old version only fires an event when you release the mouse on the navigator move. old: http://jsfiddle.net/etre0/24tu2/2/
new: http://jsfiddle.net/etre0/fTwLr/

Can I disable this new behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disable the automatic redrawing when scrolling there is a new option in the highstock 1.3 api:

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#scrollbar.liveRedraw

```
scrollbar: {
    liveRedraw: false 
}
```

This fixes the problem